# How to extract vertices from the Position tab?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a set of points from a data cloud whose data I want to extract and use in a TXT file.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a text data-block named `verts.txt`

[image]

```py
import bpy

verts = [vert.co for vert in bpy.context.object.data.vertices]
bpy.data.texts['verts.txt'].write(verts.__repr__())
```

Comment: It takes about an eternity to ship. There are about 2.5 million points. maybe there is a way to speed it up somehow??